# Capturing the previous one and next one word from a sentence based on searched word and start position

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to retrieve the previous one and next one word of the searched word **based on the searched word and his start position**(character index of the searched word in the string and starting from 0) from a string in java.
For example, if I have a string as follows:

```
I am a teacher and a father.
```

*If given a searched word is :* ***a***
*and his start position：* ***4***
*the output should be:*

```
am a teacher
```

*If given a searched word is : **a**

and his start position：**18**

the output should be:*

```
and a father
```

Any ideas?
EDIT: Keep in mind I need to use the start position as there may be duplicate words in the string.

Comment: I want the output as:
"am a teacher"
not:
"and a father"

Comment: Have a look at split method of String class.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma could you give a more detail explain?

Comment: What do you mean by starting position? If you mean character index starting from 0, than you shoud get `a teacher` (if the previous word is not mandatory). If it is mandatory, than you would get `and a father`. By the way, is `I have a string:` part of the test sequence?

Comment: @vnov Thank you remind, I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String searchedWordContext(String sentence, String searchedWord) {
    if (sentence == null || searchedWord == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("May not be null");
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    int searchedIndex = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].equals(searchedWord)) searchedIndex = i;
        // first occurence - abort
        if (searchedIndex!=-1) break;
    }
    if (searchedIndex == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Searched word: " + searchedWord + " not found in sentence: " + sentence);
    if (words.length < 2) return searchedWord;
    if (searchedIndex == 0) return words[searchedIndex] + " "+ words[serchedIndex+1];
    if (searchedIndex == words.length) return words[searchedIndex-1] + " "+ words[searchedIndex];
    return words[searchedIndex-1] + " " + words[searchedIndex] + " " + words[searchedIndex+1];
}
```

Comment: In this method, only get the "and a father", because use"(words[i].equals(searchedWord) searchedIndex = i;" only get the last index of "a".

Comment: Thanks. I want to capture the previous one and next one word from a sentence based on searched word and **start position**._`Position meaning character index of the searched word in the string and starting from 0`_  not just first occurence.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String queryExamples(String sentence,int selectedPosition) {
    StringBuffer queries = new StringBuffer();
    if (selectedPosition > sentence.length()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The selected position must be less than sentence length.");
        }
        String[] afterWords = sentence.substring(selectedPosition).split(" ");
        String afterWord = "";
        String beforeWord = "";
        if (afterWords.length == 1) {
            afterWord = "";
        } else {
            afterWord = afterWords[1];
        }

        if(selectedPosition==0){
            beforeWord = "";
        } else {
            String[] WordList = sentence.substring(0, selectedPosition).split(" ");
            if (WordList.length > 0) {
                beforeWord = WordList[WordList.length - 1];
            }
        }
        queries.append(beforeWord).append(" ").append(afterWord);

    }

    return queries;
}
```